# how to add one list with another list?

Tags: python, list

I want to add an list with another list this is what i mean i there is 2 lists and u want to add `list1[0]` with `list2[0]` obviously there will be more than just 1 values in the lists, also i get no erros.

my code:

```
list1 = [7,9,0,9,4,9]
list2 = [2,6,9,0,3,7]

for num1 in range(len(list1)):
  pass
pass

for num2 in range(len(list2)):
  x = list1[num1]+list2[num2]
  print(x)
pass
```

my output:

```
11
15
18
9
12
16
```

what my should be:

```
9
15
9
9
7
16
```

Comment: `list3=[x+y for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]`

Comment: Or, `for i, x in enumerate(list1): print(x+list2[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `list1[num2]` in line 9 instead `list1[num1]`.

```py
x = list1[num2]+list2[num2]
```

```py
list1 = [7,9,0,9,4,9]
list2 = [2,6,9,0,3,7]

for num1 in range(len(list1)):
  pass
pass

for num2 in range(len(list2)):
  x = list1[num2]+list2[num2]
  print(x)
pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

or

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> list( map(add, list1, list2) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use zip(list1,list2) with List Comprehension.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

list12 = [x+y for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]

print(list12)
```

Method 2 :

```
from  operator import add
aa = list(map(add,list1,list2))
print(aa)
```

```
Output   
[5, 7, 9]
```